# Django send_mail DNS_NAME error

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

Got a strange error in my django app when trying to send an email from a contact form.

In DEBUG got a unicode error when submitting my contact form.

After looking at the traceback, the string that caused the unicode error was the DNS_NAME in the function CachedDnsName() in utils.py

The function returned my laptop's name, which is 'Portátil-HP'

I get the unicode error, but why is it happening?

settings.py

```
# Email setup
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

views.py

```
class Contactos(FormView):
  @staticmethod
  def get(request):
    return render(request, 'site/contactos.html', {'form': Formulario()})

  def post(self, request):
    form = Formulario(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        send_mail(name, message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'site/contactos.html', {'form': Formulario()})
    else:
        return render(request, 'site/contactos.html', {'form': Formulario()})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS_NAME should be in ascii (like a domain name), your `á` is likely breaking it.

As far as I'm aware there's no way to set the DNS_NAME manually (see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6989))

The only solution might be to change the name of your laptop to something with simpler characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these as well:

```
EMAIL_FROM = 'emailtosentfrom@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'emailtosenterrorsfrom@gmail.com'
```